# Do Not Call Directives

Tags: debt, donotcall

In the U.S. debt collection companies who are told to not call a debtor are required to cease all cellphone contact attempts.

Does this Do Not Call command apply only to the debt collection company who received it? If the debt collection company was owned by another company, could they pass the do not call number to the parent company or a sister company to bypass the do not call?